# How do I install an SVN client on amazon micro ec2 server (Amazon Linux)

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, svn

I'm using a commercial Subversion server on the cloud (Assembla) and I have an Amazon micro server with Amazon Linux. I want to install an SVN client on that machine.

I know rapidSVN runs on Linux, but I dont know if it's supported on Amazon Linux and if it is, how to set it up. Which can I SVN and how do I set it up? (I prefer a client with a GUI interface)

Comment: If you have Java there, you may use SVNKit (java implementation of SVN) or any client based on it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVNKit#Adoption

Answer (score 12):

I'm pretty sure amazon linux is RPM based, you'll want to install svn via yum:

```
sudo yum install subversion
```

Comment: is this a pre-installed client on linux? which type of client is it. Does it have a graphical interface?

Comment: It will install a command line subversion, and you really should learn to use `svn` on the command line. BTW, you could prefer learning and using `git`

Comment: This are the console client libraries. Check out the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/).

Comment: It will be harder to configure a graphical interface on amazon linux then learn to use subversion with the command line.